# Is there any source that shows all of Earth's terrain changes from Pangea to present?

Tags: plate-tectonics, earth-history, resources

I teach a class on my state's history to middle school students. Our textbooks do not cover much historical geology, but its a subject students are fascinated in, and feel needs to be added.

I want to present my students with a basic understanding of (1) how the state initially formed (2) the major geological changes that occurred since then, and then (3) show how these impacted climate, flaura, and fauna changes.

I'm struggling to match up the information from the geologists, paleontologists, and archaeologists in this way. The paleontology books, for instance, speak of aquatic dinosaurs during the Triassic period, then I turn to geology books during that time, and there are no mention of water levels anywhere...and similar issues where the information doesn't seem to match, or at least, don't provide a comprehensive "big picture" of what is going on.

This leads me to wonder if there is any source that presents a comprehensive view of changes to the World (or at least North America) across time? This could be an Atlas, detailed book of maps, on-line time line, or maybe even some software modelling and showing the changes, just something to help visualize what happened to a layperson.

Comment: Well, there are [these animations](https://www.google.com/search?q=scotese+plate+tectonics+animation&oq=scotese+tectonic).

Comment: [Ancient Earth Globe](https://dinosaurpictures.org/ancient-earth#50) . The total volume of the oceans doesn't change much except in "snowball Earth". [Various interactive timelines.](https://www.google.com/search?q=earth+timeline+interactive)